# Коли варто вживати архаїчні чи застарілі слова?

Tags: вживання-слів, архаїзми

Часто в словниках бачу позначки того, що якийсь з перекладів є архаїзмом чи застарілим варіантом.

- Коли варто вживати такі слова?
- Чи варто запам'ятовувати такі слова?
- Яка різниця між архаїзмом і застарілим словом?

Comment: (1) Треба бути обачним з словниками. Десь читав статтю з прикладами, що Совєти слова навмисно позначали дїялектами чи архаїзмами. Тут наче [приклад](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B4). (2) Зазвичай такі слова запамʼятовуються пасивно, та й це дещо субʼєктивне запитання, як на мене. (3) [Різниця](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um19.htm): застарілї — вийшли взагалї з вжитку, архаїзми — мають сучаснї вживанї замінники.

Comment: (4) А вживати: як художньо чи як свій стиль. Теж дещо субʼєктивне запитання, на мою, звісно, думку. Себто все від свого наміру: чи бажаєш аби оточення зрозуміло, з можливістю зрозуміти чи навпаки — взагалї нїц.

Comment: @Follower чому б не перенести це у відповідь?

Comment: НМД, із трьох пунктів запитання лише останній може мати обʼєктивну відповідь. Перші два вимагають уточнення, бо «варто» — це суто субʼєктивне слово. Комусь «варто», а комусь — ні.

Comment: @bytebuster я не проти почути декілька думок.

Comment: @Yola, ні, не зовсім так. Primarily Opinion-based запитання підлягають закриттю, а не битві of opinionated answers. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Застарілі слова бувають двох типів:

- Історизми
- Архаїзми

[Історизми](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) - назви предметів і явищ, яких сьогодні вже немає або вони вийшли з ужитку: мушкет, боярин, пищаль.

[Архаїзми](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%B7%D0%BC) - слова, вирази, граматичні форми, які вийшли з ужитку і мають сучасні аналоги (синонімічні форми). Вікіпедія наводить такі типи архаїзмів:

> 1. власне лексичні — слова, що застаріли в цілому (чадо, ректи, понеже);
> 2. лексико-фонетичні, що відрізняються від сучас. варіантів тільки одним чи кількома звуками або місцем наголосу (сей, пашпорт, глас, піїт, філозоф);
> 3. лексико-морфологічні — застар. словоформи та грамат. характеристики слова (люде — сучас. люди, авто — раніше ч. p.);
> 4. лексико-словотвірні, що відрізняються від сучас. однокорен. синонімів словотв. формантом — суфіксом або префіксом (податель, подаяніє, возгордитися);
> 5. лексико-семантичні, у яких застар. є лише окр. значення (броня у знач, ‘зброя’, худий ‘поганий’, машина ‘паровоз, поїзд’, пор. машиніст).

З власного досвіду - у словниках "заст." використовується для історизмів. В радянській практиці (наскільки мені відомо) точилася боротьба між лінгвістами-укладачами словників та функціонерами що слідкували за ідейною чистотою (принаймні на початку ХХ сторіччя). Тому слова щодо релігійного життя, назви, пов'язані із царським режимом, небажані соціальні явища (проституція) і т.і. допускалися у словники із поміткою "застаріле".

Щодо української лінгвістики, то начебто через політику наближення української мови до російської "небажані" українські слова відмічали як "діалектичні", щодо "архаїзмів" не впевнений, але може бути і таке. (*Upd:* Стаття [Лінгвоцид](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B4) у Вікіпедії, що її знайшов Follower має приклади таких "архаїзмів", наприклад слово "відсоток").

Чи варто запам'ятовувати такі слова чи вживати їх? Як бачимо, застарілі слова розбиваються на різні групи, тому однієї відповіді на всі випадки немає. Зрозуміло що без історизмів неможливо говорити про минуле. Щодо архаїзмів - частину з них використовують в літературі для "високого стилю" - чадо, чоло і т.і.

У будь-якому разі, архаїзми надають мові певного стилістичного забарвлення, тому їх треба уникати якщо такий ефект небажаний (наприклад у діловому листуванні і т.і.).

Answer (score 0):

Тобі варто вживати застарілі чи архаїчні слова коли:

1. Інші слова не підходять (як у науковому творі з лінгвістики чи історії, наприклад).
2. Ти хочеш спантеличити аудиторію або розмішити її.
3. Ти хочеш звучати претензійно чи повчально.

Comment: -1: Ця відповідь виглядає як особиста, нічим не підтверджена, думка автора.